# What equation do I have to put here to have an accurate increase of 4.7% every year?

Tags: percentages

I'm dragging this question over from another website from a recommendation.

I'm writing a program in BlueJ that gets the starting price of Tuition in the first year ($8000) and for each year afterwards the price raises by 4.7%.

```
public class Tuition
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int years;  
        final double Tuition = 8000;
        double Price;
        years = 1;
        System.out.printf("%15s %15s\n", "Year", "Tuition Price");
        while (years <= 4)
        {
            Price = years + 8000;
            System.out.printf("%15d %15.1f\n", years, Price);
            years ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now obviously the only line (I think) I need help with is

```
 Price = years + 8000;
```

Because right now with the way I have it it just adds 8000 to every year. (8001 for year one, 8002 for year two, etc.)

What's the equation I would write in that line to get the yearly 4.7% increase? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> Price = 8000 * ((1+ 0.047)^years);

**Edit**: if you want to avoid "^", initiate before the loop with

> Price = 8000;

then, inside the loop, replace

> Price = years + 8000;

with

> Price = Price * 1.047;

The rest of the code stays unchanged.

Comment: I tried that but I got "bad operand types for binary operator '^' first type: double; second type: int"

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: It worked well enough that I figured out the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the formula for **[compound interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest)**.

So your line should be:

```
Price = 8000 * (1.047^years)
```

I don't know Java, so I don't know if `^` is the right operator here. But you want to raise 1.047 to the power of the number of years.